# I can not add in file full name only add one char, so how do i add full string in file?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
char *in()
{
    char *a[100];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("\na : %d",&a);
    return(a);
}

int main()
{
    char *b;
    int i,j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("asif.txt","w");
    b=in();
    printf("\nb : %d",b);
    for(j=0;j<strlen(b);j++)
    {
        putc(b[j],fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format your post. But before that you should probably read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You probably need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) too, and read up on pointers and arrays, and scoping.

Comment: Right beside `putc()`, there's also a [`puts()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts).

Comment: Why used & in printf()??

Comment: `return(a);` is always wrong. Because it is returning a pointer to a local function variable which is not valid after the function exits. Also, `char *a[100];` should be `char a[100];`.

Comment: i was printing address &a  using

Comment: store `strlen(b)` in a variable outside the loop. You're calling it again and again each for loop

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a number of fundamental misconceptions about C syntax that are giving you problems, e.g.

```
char *in()
{
    char *a[100];
    scanf("%s",&a);
    printf("\na : %d",&a);
    return(a);
}
```

- `char *a[100];` declares an `'array or pointers to char'` (`100` of them)
- It is declared local inside `in` and thus will be destroyed when function `in` returns (the function stack-frame is destroyed/released at that point).
- You do not need an `'array or pointers to char'`, you need either a `character-array` of sufficient size to hold the longest word read as input, or you need to allocate a block of memory of that same size (providing space for the *nul-terminating* character at the end)
- `printf("\na : %d",&a)` attempts to print the address of the array of pointers using a *decimal* format specifier. If you are attempting to print a pointer address, use `%p`.
- However, if you want to print the current word read as input, you need to use `%s` to print the string.
- In either case, you would NOT use the **address of** operator before `a`.
- You declare `in` as type `char *`, but then attempt to return type `char *[100]` - your compiler should be spewing warnings and errors (read them, you can learn more C from reading and eliminating all warnings and errors, than just about anywhere else)

It would make `in` more useful to pass `FILE *fp` as a parameter and use `fscanf` within the function to allow reading from any file. Simply pass `stdin` to read from *standard input*.

You also need to pass a character array of sufficient size to `in`. Providing storage for `b` in `main` and passing it as a parameter to `in` is what it looks like you are intending to do. (you can also dynamically allocate memory in `in` with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, but then you have the responsibility to `free` any memory you allocate. Better to just create storage for `b` in `main` and pass it to `in`.

Putting that together, it looks like you intended something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define MAX 100 /* longest word in the unabridged dictionary is 27-chars */

char *in (FILE *fp, char *a)
{
    if (fscanf (fp, "%99s", a) != EOF) { /* always validate ALL input */
        printf ("a : %s\n", a);
        return(a);
    }
    else
        return NULL;    /* return NULL on EOF to indicate done reading */
}

int main (void)
{
    char b[MAX] = "";   /* declare b with 100 chars and initialize */
    FILE *fp;

    if (!(fp = fopen ("asif.txt","w"))) { /* validate ALL file openingings */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed 'asif.txt'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (in (stdin, b))       /* for each word in input  */
        fprintf (fp, "%s", b);  /* write it to output file */

    fclose(fp);     /* close file */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat data.txt
Abbie 3.4 Oakley 3.5 Sylvia 3.6 Uwe 3.7 Ken 3.8 Aaron 3.9 Fabien 4
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fprintftofile <dat/data.txt
a : Abbie
a : 3.4
a : Oakley
a : 3.5
a : Sylvia
a : 3.6
a : Uwe
a : 3.7
a : Ken
a : 3.8
a : Aaron
a : 3.9
a : Fabien
a : 4
```

**File Output**

```
$ cat asif.txt
Abbie3.4Oakley3.5Sylvia3.6Uwe3.7Ken3.8Aaron3.9Fabien4
```

(note: you haven't put any spaces between the words written to `'asif.txt'` or included any of the `'\n'`s)

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions, or if your intent was different than I took it to be.

**Note:** Always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning or error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've entirely understood what you are looking for. 
What I have understood so far is that you are asking if you can put multiple char at once in a file.
My answer to that would be that [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) or [puts()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm) are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: [fprintf()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm)...

Comment: Oh... Well... That's because... OK, I had completely forgotten fprintf existence. My bad. I believe the author don't need the string formatting though.